# How to rename suffix in column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to replace 2003 with x, 2004 with y, and 2005 with z, in the column suffixes.
For example, I would like to transform:

[image]

In:

[image]

Here's the reproducible example:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xd_2004 = c(1, 1, 1, 1,
1), xd_2003 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xe_2004 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xe_2003 = c(1,
1, 1, 1, 1), xd_2005 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xe_2005 = c(1, 1, 1,
1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may also use a named vector in `str_replace_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_replace_all(.x, setNames(c('x', 'y', 'z'), 2003:2005)))
```

-output

```
  id xd_y xd_x xe_y xe_x xd_z xe_z
1  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
2  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
3  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
4  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
5  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `rename_with` we could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., '2004', "y")) %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., '2003', "x")) %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., '2005', "z"))
```

```
id xd_y xd_x xe_y xe_x xd_z xe_z
1  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
2  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
3  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
4  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
5  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```